# Closure expression is unused swift 3

Tags: swift, if-statement

> Closure expression is unused Error

Can anyone solve the problem and how can I make it correctly and how can I use `if else` statement in the code without problem?

```
func storeToCoreData(product_Name : String,product_Brand : String,original_Price : String,discount_Price : String,userPhotoString : String,catagory : String, urlCoreData : String){
    if  catagory == "Tools" {
            switch (urlCoreData){
            case "Mens_shirt":
            coreVariables.mens_Shirt.StoreProduct(product_Name: product_Name, product_Brand: product_Brand, product_Price: original_Price, product_Discount: discount_Price, product_Image: userPhotoString)
        break
            case "Mens_sweatshirt" :
            coreVariables.mens_SweatShirt.StoreProduct(product_Name: product_Name, product_Brand: product_Brand, product_Price: original_Price, product_Discount: discount_Price, product_Image: userPhotoString)
        break
            case "Mens_tshirt":
            coreVariables.mens_Tshirt.StoreProduct(product_Name: product_Name, product_Brand: product_Brand, product_Price: original_Price, product_Discount: discount_Price, product_Image: userPhotoString)
        break
            default:
                break
        }
    } else {
        switch (urlCoreData){
            case "Women_kurta" :
            coreVariables.womens_Kurta.StoreProduct(product_Name: product_Name, product_Brand: product_Brand, product_Price: original_Price, product_Discount: discount_Price, product_Image: userPhotoString)
        break
            case "Women_saree" :
            coreVariables.womens_Saree.StoreProduct(product_Name: product_Name, product_Brand: product_Brand, product_Price: original_Price, product_Discount: discount_Price, product_Image: userPhotoString)
        break
            case "Women_tops":
            coreVariables.womens_Tops.StoreProduct(product_Name: product_Name, product_Brand: product_Brand, product_Price: original_Price, product_Discount: discount_Price, product_Image: userPhotoString)
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    } else {
        switch (urlCoreData){
        case "first" :
            coreVariables.first.StoreProduct(product_Name: product_Name, product_Brand: product_Brand, product_Price: original_Price, product_Discount: discount_Price, product_Image: userPhotoString)
            break
        case "second" :
            coreVariables.second.StoreProduct(product_Name: product_Name, product_Brand: product_Brand, product_Price: original_Price, product_Discount: discount_Price, product_Image: userPhotoString)
            break
        case "third":
            coreVariables.third.StoreProduct(product_Name: product_Name, product_Brand: product_Brand, product_Price: original_Price, product_Discount: discount_Price, product_Image: userPhotoString)
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is Swift:

- No break statements in `switch` cases (except `default`)
- No parentheses around the `switch` argument
- No *snake_cased* variable names.

---

The error occurs because the first `else` clause catches all cases where `catagory != "Tools"` so the second `else` will never be reached.

If you need the second `else` you have to insert a second `if` condition for example

```
if catagory == "Tools" {
   ...
} else if catagory == "Something Else" {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```